# Gulp CSS way to separate font shorthand during build?

Tags: css, fonts

Is there is at build process to parse out css font into its independent parts?

So

```
font:500 3em/1.2 Arial, sans-serif;
```

into

```
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 3em;
line-height: 1.2;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS itself does not do parsing. There are built-in shortcuts, but they're the only shortcuts you're allowed to use. You cannot write your own yourself in CSS alone.

If you were using a parsing language like SCSS, you could write your own functions to do that for you:

```
@mixin my_font_function($weight, $size, $height, $family) {
    font: {
        weight: $weight;
        size: $size;
        family: $family;
    }
    line-height: $height;
}
```

Then this:

```
div.class{
    @include my_font_function(500, 3em, 1.2, "Arial, sans-serif");
}
```

would produce:

```
div.class {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

once it had compiled.